# how to align pic to the same line of the radio button?

Tags: html, css, radio-button, inline

I already did the float and inline but doesn't work. hope you guys help me.
it goes like this

```
<form action="#">
<input type="radio" class="inline" name="pay" value="visa"><img src="pic1.gif">
<input type="radio" class="inline" name="pay" value="master"><img src="pic2.gif">
<input type="radio" class="inline" name="pay" value="paypal"><img src="pic3.jpg">
</form>
```

*
*
*

```
the output goes like this:
         ---------
         '  pic  '
         '-------'


     *radio

i want it to be like this:
             ---------
      *radio '  pic  '
             '-------'
```

CSS:

```
.inline {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `vertical-align:middle` to `img` tag

**HTML**

```
<form action="#">
    <input type="radio" class="inline" name="pay" value="visa"><img src="http://www.m8betting.com/M8betting/Upload/3746/thumbs/image_placeholder8.gif">
    <input type="radio" class="inline" name="pay" value="master"><img src="http://www.m8betting.com/M8betting/Upload/3746/thumbs/image_placeholder8.gif">
    <input type="radio" class="inline" name="pay" value="paypal"><img src="http://www.m8betting.com/M8betting/Upload/3746/thumbs/image_placeholder8.gif">
</form>
```

**CSS**

```
img{
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

[Fiddle Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/k1nqb81t/)

Comment: can i make it a class? i have other images on my webpage

Comment: yes you can, also you can use the class "inline_img" (see below sample link) in the form tag to make it occur once and update  your css like (.inline_img img{vertical-align:middle;}  http://jsfiddle.net/k1nqb81t/1/

Answer (score 1):

**Define your** `input` `radio` and `img` tag this `css`

```
    .inline,.inline + img{
     display:inline-block;
   vertical-align:middle
    }
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/1p8mdomm/)**

Answer (score 0):

Use `vertical-align:middle; float:left;`